# mentioning one out of the group in comparison

Tags: comparison

```
After the teacher, X is the most knowledgeable among all students.
```

Is this sentence ok? I feel something weird in this:

Using 'among all students' can this student (x) be compared while following the phrase 'after the teacher'? I don't think so; because 'the teacher' is not part of the group (all students), right? X's level of knowledge is the highest to all but his level is lower than that of the teacher.

```
After the teacher, X is the most knowledgeable as far as the students are concerned.
```

Does it look ok?

Comment: Your sentence doesn't make sense, because the teacher ***isn't*** included in "all students" in the first place, so you can't say ***apart from*** him. But in reality I can't see any reason to mention the teacher at all (unless you wanted to somehow imply that the teacher might ***not*** be more knowledgeable than the students, which seems a bit unlikely).

Comment: that's what i am confused for.  All three (the teacher, X and other students) have to be mentioned in the sentence.

Comment: ***Why*** mention the teacher in this statement?

Comment: because it is a gathering where the level of knowledge of every presence is being discussed

Comment: I think you need a longer sentence to coherently mention the obvious fact that the teacher is more knowledgeable than ***all*** his pupils (why else would he be teaching them?), but that pupil X is the wisest ***among the pupils***.

Comment: you are right. i wish if i could find a conjunction to say this in a shorter sentence

Comment: it's just as well there are no female teachers, which would make English a lot more complicated, especially when writing about school matters.

Comment: **Apart from the teacher, X is the most knowledgeable person in the classroom.**

Comment: @JeffreyCarney: Thanks for that. I don't know why it never occurred to me that ***people in the classroom*** includes both the teacher *and* all the pupils, making it easy to succinctly rank X *below the teacher, but above all the **other** people in the classroom*. What I like about your phrasing is that it quite naturally accommodates the word ***obviously*** after ***teacher*** to avoid that observation seeming somewhat "trite".